# C programming - Operator

Tags: c

I have written a simple code which accepts password from user and checks if it contains UpperCase letter, digit and special character. The password should of length 3.

Problem:

User should get three trials before it ends. Code works perfectly well in case if the password is correct but in case of wrong it keeps on asking infinitely. I think that increment operator for increasing the attempt is not working (or I am making any mistake).

Thanks for help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0, letter=0, digit=0, character=0;
    int attempt=0;
    char password[3];

    while(attempt<3)
    {
        printf("\nAttempt: %d\n", attempt);
        printf("\nPlease enter the 3 character password containing Letter in upper case, digit & special character: \n");
        scanf(" %s", password);

        for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
        {
            if(isalpha(password[i]))
            {
                if(isupper(password[i]))
                {
                    letter=1;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Wrong Password (Upper case letter needed)\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(isdigit(password[i]))
            {
                digit=1;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                character=1;
            }
        }
        if(letter==1 && digit==1 && character==1)
        {
            printf("You have entered correct password\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You have entered wrong password Try again\n");
            attempt++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be of length 3 you need to declare `char password[4];` instead of `char password[3];`, also, use `"%3s"` in `scanf` in order to avoid buffer overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you've to declare the password array of size 4 because you've a `\0` character at the end of your word. Here's the code, I just changed few lines.

```
int main(){
int i=0, letter=0, digit=0, character=0;
int attempt=0;
char password[4]; /*For a string of 3 character you must declare it of 4 because '\0' */
while(attempt<3){
    printf("\nAttempt: %d\n", attempt);
    printf("\nPlease enter the 3 character password containing Letter in upper case, digit & special character: \n");
    scanf(" %3s", password);
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(isalpha(password[i])){
            if(isupper(password[i])){
                letter=1;
                continue;
            }else{
            printf("Wrong Password (Upper case letter needed)\n");
            break;
            }
        }else if(isdigit(password[i])){
            digit=1;
            continue;
        }else{
            character=1;
        }
    }
    if(letter==1 && digit==1 && character==1){
        printf("You have entered correct password\n");
        break;
    }
    printf("You have entered wrong password Try again\n");
    attempt++; /*You can increase it here because if you enter the correct password you'll exit*/
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Solved. It was mistake of array size. Silly mistake!.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have one very serious bug in your program. The `password` array is too short to hold a string of 3 characters. Remember that C strings requires a NUL-termination. This means that to store the string "Ab!" you really need 4 bytes of memory as it will be stored as `'a''b''!''\0'`. Since you have only reserved 3 bytes for password, your code will write outside the reserved memory if the user enters 3 characters. That is undefined behavior.

> Can that explain why your code continues infinitely?

Well, if you have undefined behavior, it is said that anything can happen - so yes! What may happen is that when writing the `'\0'` (i.e. 0) outside `password` it may overwrite (parts of) `attempt` and set it back to zero. It is hard to say whether this is what happens as it depends on the specific system.

So the important thing is:

```
char password[3]; --> char password[4];
```

Next thing:

You need to reset the counters in each attempt. That is:

```
while(attempt<3)
{
    letter=0;
    digit=0;
    character=0;
    ....
```

If you don't, you may get false positives as the result from one attempt is carried on to the next.

Finally - never ever do:

```
    scanf(" %s", password);
```

The user can overflow the input buffer (i.e. `password`) by typing more than 3 letters before hitting enter. Instead use `fgets`. If you really want `scanf` at least put at limit to the length of the input like:

```
    scanf(" %3s", password);
```

Comment: Solved. It was mistake of array size. Silly mistake!. Thanks a lot